# Matlab function for check matrix equality, without order

Tags: matlab, matrix

I was wondering if there's a matlab function that checks if two matrices have the same elements which are not necessarily in order.

Example: A = [1,2,3] and B = [3,2,1]

the function isequal(A,B) returns 0, but what I want is a function or code that will return 1. I know I can iterate through the matrix, but I'm wondering if there's a faster way to do it. Thanks,

Comment: What about elements that occur several times? Is `[1, 2, 3]` equal to `[1, 2, 3, 3]` or not? That is, are your matrices sets or multisets?

Answer (score 2):

A simple way for vectors could be

```
isequal(sort(A), sort(B))
```

For matrices use

```
isequal(sort(A(:)), sort(B(:)))
```

However, sorting might be slow for large matrices.

Answer (score 1):

### Set vs. Multiset

This depends on whether you want to treat multiple occurrences of the same number as individual items (multiset approach) or not (set approach):

Are `[1, 2, 3]` and `[1, 2, 3, 3]` the same (set approach) or not (multiset approach)?

### Set Approach

As suggested by reverse_engineer:

```
f_xor = @(x, y) isempty(setxor(x, y))
```

A set-variant of H. Muster's approach:

```
 f_sortu = @(x, y) isequal(sort(unique(x(:))), sort(unique(y(:))))
```

### Multiset Approach

As suggested by H.Muster:

```
f_sort = @(x, y) isequal(sort(x(:)), sort(y(:)))
```

### Timings

Here timings for the individual variants.

```
>> A = rand(1, 1000);
>> B = A; B(end) = B(end) - 1;  % Make vectors almost equal
>> N = 10000;
>> tic; for i = 1 : N; f_sort(A, B); end; toc/N

ans =

   1.6892e-04

>> tic; for i = 1 : N; f_sortu(A, B); end; toc/N

ans =

   3.5647e-04

>> tic; for i = 1 : N; f_xor(A, B); end; toc/N

ans =

   5.4098e-04
```

The set approaches are slower because they need to remove duplicates. Interestingly, `setxor` is slower than using `sort` + `unique`.

Comment: Interesting point. Strange that `sort`+`unique` is quicker than `setxor`... Makes me wonder whether or not there's a better implementation possible for `setxor`...

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to check emptiness of `setxor`:

```
isempty(setxor(set1,set2))
```

Not sure if this is faster than the `sort` option though...

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
setdiff(A,B)
```

which is almost the inverse of what you seek.

Comment: beware `setdiff` returns the elements in A that are not in B. This is not exactly what the OP is looking for, as checking for emptiness of the result would not guarantee identity...